# How many times is the data packet copied before finally reaching the NIC?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-interface, tcp, tcp-ip

On a typical linux machine, how many times would packets be copied from the application layer to all the way in its journey to the network card. I am assuming the protocol being used here is TCP/IP with the standard implementation of linux kernel network stack and no custom modifications.

I am aware that TCP maintains a buffer (or a window) for congestion and flow control and the size of this window determines how many packets you can send at once before waiting for ACKs. My  understanding is that at least one copy has to be performed from application's memory into the operating system's transport layer handler memory because the linux network stack is kernel implementation and application is a process running in user address space.

I would like to know a detailed description.

Comment: could be as much as 6 times, but it probably is 3 times .... google `7 layer osi model` and `4 layer tcp/ip model`

Comment: @jsotola even if the implementation matched one of those layered models (it doesn’t), there wouldn’t have to be one copy per change of layer...

Comment: As @StephenKitt mentioned, I agree that layered model does not necessarily translate to copying for each layer. Copying from Layer 4 to Layer 3 does not make sense as it might happen that the same kernel process take care of it or share it via pointers.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/726917/) ...